# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object - Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, controller

I am trying to upload an image within my form data

here is the form header

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'doAddProject', 'file'=>'true', 'method'=>'PUT')) }}
```

and here is the controller

```
public function store()
    {
        $project = new Projects();

        $file = Input::file('pImage');
        $destination_path = 'images/projects/';
        $filename = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destination_path, $filename);

        $project->main_image = Input::file($filename);
        $project->pro_title = Input::get('pName');
        $project->pro_map = Input::get('pMap');
        $project->pro_description = Input::get('pDetails');
        $project->pro_serves = implode(",", array_filter(Input::get('pro_serves')));
        $project->pro_activity = Input::get('activity');
        $project->save();

        return Redirect::to('admin/view-project')->with('message', 'Project add successfully');
    }
```

Got Error :

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Comment: in your form tag change 'file'=>'true' to 'files'=>'true'

Comment: @Zeus I don't think so, this is not the problem, even I try this I got `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'main_image' cannot be null`

Comment: Also check your php.ini file and check for Post_max_size or upload_max_size if your image size exceeds this limit the image wont be uploaded.

Comment: And Integrity constraint violation error is thrown by the database cause u are entering null in a non nullable column ie main_image and in your code i dont see the column main_image being given a value.

Comment: @Zeus I am sure it's not `exceeds this limit the image` I am working on localhost, and these are the database construction I have `type:blob, Null:No, Default:None`

Comment: What about the column main_image cause thats the column throwing the error in the table

Comment: Like I just said it's like so `type:blob, Null:No, Default:None`

Comment: Excatly in your code you are not setting any value to that column, that is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123850/discussion-between-yousef-altaf-and-zeus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Line

```
$project->main_image = Input::file($filename);
```

Change it to

```
$project->main_image = $filename;
```